# SageMaker AWS Binary Text Classification

Tags: python, nlp, amazon-sagemaker

Can AWS SageMaker handle binary classification using TFidf vectorized text as prediction base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use inference pipeline for your use case. What that means is that you will need to use a pre-processing step to featurize your text into tfidf and then feed into Sagemaker classification. Here's a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57767899/how-to-create-a-pipeline-in-sagemaker-with-pytorch) with more details around this.